# Which matte or very low glare large size (30"/35") monitor?

Tags: monitors, displays

I'm looking for a new monitor for my workstation. Unluckily, in my office the lighting is a bit weird, generating a lot of reflections, so I'd like a real-matte monitor like they used to make some years ago (and they sometimes still produce on 24"/27" monitors); but recent, large displays seem to be mostly semi-glossy or glossy. I can tell the glossiness of the AOC U3477PQU is excessive, as an example.

So, I'd like a suggestion for a display that:

- Has a size between 30" and 35"
- Resolution is not THAT important, but I'd like a 3440x1440 or 3840x2160 display (I don't have a real bond on aspect ratio)
- DP 1.2 (I don't have HDMI 2.0 on my laptop)
- Available in Europe
- Absolutely **matte or extremely low glare**

Comment: A thin transparent film would do the job for any monitor if fitted correctly. Even a matte privacy filter.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly get one of those 3M privacy screen covers? Produces a matte display and adds some extra security.

LINK: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=3m+privacy+screen+pc&rlz=1C1GCEA_enGB749GB749&oq=3m+privacy+screen+pc&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.8751j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=3m+privacy+screen+pc&tbm=shop

Answer (score 0):

## Monitor hood

A [monitor hood](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=monitor+hood&t=osx&ia=products) might be a better way to go than a matte screen. A hood is a simple less expensive solution. Graphics professionals always use a monitor hood, to go easier on their eyes and to perceive more accurate colors.

And getting a hood frees you up to choose any kind of monitor you wish, based on other criteria.

[image]

Comment: Unlucily, there's a window quite directly beyond me. I think the hood won't prevent that light.

Comment: I suggest improvising with some cardboard as an experiment. You might be surprised how well it works. Also, taping up some sheer white fabric in the window can cut the glare while still admitting light.